# How to decrypt result of query when using the Hyperledger Client SDK for Node.js

Tags: node.js, blockchain, hyperledger

In the [Hyperledger Client SDK for Node.js](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/master/sdk/node#hyperledger-client-sdk-for-nodejs) , how can I decrypt the results of the query that are returned in the results variable below ?

```
tx.on('complete', function (results) {
       console.log('Results          [%j]', results);
```

The console.log shows a message like :

```
Results          ["7b22496e766f6963654944223a2269303031222c22436c69656e744944223a2269303031222c224e616d65223a224c656e6f766f2047726f7570204c74642e222c22416d6f756e74223a3130303030307d"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough, the result is hex-encoded - not actually sure why - will need to look more into the SDK implementation although it might be hex encoded in case the actual contents were encrypted as well.  In this case, it is just a hex-encoded string:

```
tx.on('complete', function (results) {
   console.log('Results:[%j]', new Buffer(results,'hex').toString());
}
```

should work